# Training EfficientNet always throws CUDA exhausted error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have been trying a hands on the EfficientNet-B6 architecture but evertime I try to train the same, It simply throws up CUDA resource exhausted error. I have been training it on 16GB Tesla P100